# Is there a way to define an own code formatting rule in Resharper?

Tags: javascript, resharper

In Resharper there is very few Javascript fortmatting rules. 
For example I want to format an object array is this way:

```
    [{
         a: 1,
         b: 2 
     },{
         a: 3,
         b: 4 
     }];
```

Is that possible to define a rule by myself without writing an extension plugin?